# Blackberry setting the position of a RichtextField in FullScreen

Tags: blackberry, layout, user-interface

I am writing an application in BlackBerry, where I want to do some custom painting at the top portion of the screen in the paint method of FullScreen and at the same time, I want a RichtextField positioned at the lower portion of the screen. I tried using setPosition methods in the Field class, but to no avail. So how do I set the position of the RichtextField that is added to the FullScreen class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SpacerField` for that purpose:

```
class SpacerField extends Field {

  int localWidth, localHeight;

  SpacerField(int width, int height) {
    super(Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
    localWidth = width;
    localHeight = height;
  }

  protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setExtent(localWidth, localHeight);
  }


  protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

  }


  public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return localWidth;
  }

  public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return localHeight;
  }
}
```

and add it to your Screen before your RichTextField. Be sure to give a suitable `width` (`Display.getWidth()` ?) and `height` when constructing the SpacerField.

***Note:*** I had found the code at [this forum discussion](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=46477#M46477) a few months ago when I needed to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to position objects is to extend a Manager and use it to position and size the objects the way you want. Check the documentation for net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager and net.rim.device.api.ui.Field for information on how manager control their children.

Comment: FullScreen extends Manager, however when I tried to use setPositionChild() method, it threw an IllegalArgumentException saying that the Field is not a child. I have added the field to the FullScreen. Also I searched if I need to set it as a child, but there were no methods to do that.